# A word 'Poison' as an adjective

Tags: adjectives, nouns, modifiers

Can the word 'Poison' be used as an adjective?

- according to two lyrics, it can be

**[Poison heart](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/ramones/poisonheart.html)**

**[Poison apple](https://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/bloodonthedancefloor/poisonapple.html)**

*as far as I know adjective for 'Poison' is 'Poisonous', moreover, I couldn't find the proof (poison is an adjective) in a **[dictionary](https://www.lexico.com/definition/poison)***

*if 'Poison' can be an adjective or modifier- **where to find the proof or where to check such cases** if not in dictionary, it confuses at times*

Comment: Google **attributive nouns** for an explanation of nouns that act as adjectives in front of other nouns. You will find numerous helpful sites.

Answer (score 1):

"attributive nouns" act as premodifiers for nouns that come after but often attribute very different and sometimes odd qualities.

- Stone wall - is a wall that consists of stone
- Tea cup - is a cup you drink tea from
- Poison arrow - is an arrow the tip of which carries poison.

There are many other examples and you just need to feel how an attributive noun qualifies or modifies a noun ahead of it.

A "poison heart" can for instance be a heart that carries poison but which isn't poisoned and may even not be poisonous, or it can be a heart which possesses some characteristics of poison, or it can be a heart that is made of poison.

Every attributive noun should be defined by context in my opinion, otherwise it may be misunderstood and mistranslated.

Answer (score 0):

It's very common to use a noun to modify another noun in English.

For example, a car powered by a rocket engine might be called a "rocket car".

Or a hamburger with cheese on it can be called a "cheese burger".

Or a kennel used to house dogs can be called a "dog kennel".

There's no particular rule for how the modifying noun relates to the main noun. You just have to figure it out from context.

A "poison heart" is most likely a heart that contains poison, and a "poison apple" is most likely an apple that contains poison.